# $_POST Array on servers running multiple sites

Tags: php, arrays, post

How do the servers deal with the PHP arrays like: `$_POST` for example.
Is the array going to be treated separately between websites (in case of multiple websites running on the same server)?

For example, if I have website A and website B on one server, and both websites use a `$_POST` array with the exact same parameters names, is this going to cause a problem when 2 users accessing website a and the other website b at the same time and both requesting values from the `$_POST` array?

Comment: No it won't cause a problem. `$_POST` is built at request-time and the two different sites are receiving different requests so there's no interference.

Comment: You should read up on [how virtual hosting works](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html)

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is per-*request* and has nothing to do with the server name, vhost, etc.  A single request from a browser might be a POST (or a GET, HEAD, etc).  A request may have specific name/value pairs, or it may have none at all.  In either case, they are specific to that single request at that point in time.

The $_POST variable itself is unique to the specific instance of the PHP interpreter that is handling that request, just like every other variable in PHP.